# How to Set up QuartzNet to Execute Recurring Background Job?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, quartz.net, .net-4.8

In an MVC5 web application using Net 4.8, I am trying to do the following:

When launching the application, I would like a scheduler to trigger a job every 2 Minutes.
The job reads and processes messages from a message queue.

I previously used `Hangfire` for this and it worked quite well.
However, I was told not to use `Hangfire` for this application. As an alternative, I opted for `Quartz.NET` [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) but I am currently having trouble setting up and triggering
the desired action. Following the `Quartz.NET` [documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html), this is my current setup.

```cs
public class DummyJob :IJob
    {
        private readonly ISomeInterface _someInterface;

        public DummyJob(ISomeInterface someInterface)
        {
            _someInterface = someInterface;
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
             await _someInterface.ProcessMessages();
        }
    }
```

Next, the job configuration

```cs
 public class JobScheduler
    {

        public static void Start()
        {
            // Run every 2 minutes
            const string cron = @"0 0/2 * * * ?";

            ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

            var scheduler = (IScheduler)schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
            scheduler.Start();


            var job = JobBuilder.Create<DummyJob>().Build();

            var trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .Create()
                .WithCronSchedule(cron)
                .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        }
    }
```

I tried starting the job from both `Startup.cs` and `Global.asax`. Although the job was created, it did not fire when launching the application.

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            [...]
            JobScheduler.JobScheduler.Start();
    
        }
```

What am I missing in terms of setting up `QuartzNet`? Do I need to put `JobScheduler.JobScheduler.Start();` into `Global.asax.cs` or `Startup.cs`?

Comment: If you are using 3.x series of Quartz, you need to `await` scheduler methods like `Start`, `ScheduleJob` etc. Also keep a reference to scheduler that you have created, in a static variable or similar if you don't use a container.

Comment: @MarkoLahma: Thx for your input. Could you provide an example. I am still not quite sure how to implement your suggestions.

Comment: Either `await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);` if you want to do things right and go all async, otherwise `scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`